# Synchronize InterAction Distribution lists with AD Distribution Lists

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server, crm

We have a need to allow users to be email directly to a mailing list defined in InterAction.

It seems that InterAction provides the ability to create these mailing lists, but you are only able to mail to them from within the InterAction client (web and windows).

What we really need is for there to be a way to send an email to "interactionGroup@company.com".

My original idea was to enable the AD/InterAction synch and have an AD Distribution group populated (and updated) by changes to InterAction, but that only seems to go one way, AD -> InterAction.

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea sounds like the best/most reliable way to achieve what you are looking for. Having an AD group populated from InterAction by a scheduled job would allow you to use those AD groups in any application. You would have to remember to maintain those groups in InterAction, not in AD, otherwise your changes would be overwritten during the next sync. I would recommend putting all of the sync'd InterAction groups in their own OU to keep them separate from other managed AD groups.